# Install ADT Eclipse "You are installing software that contains unsigned content"

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am a newbie in Ubuntu. I want install ADT (Android Development Tools) Eclipse, but there is a popup like this:

[image]

Please someone help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected, and explained in [ADT site](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html):

> 9. Read and accept the license agreements, then click **Finish**.
>
>    If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click **OK**.

Many Eclipse plugins are unsigned, and this is just one of them. (See also a similar question in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054752/what-does-it-mean-when-android-adt-is-unsigned-eclipse))